# Change the size of turtle in python 2 on Trinket.io

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to change the size of turtle to something larger. I am not sure if I am either doing it incorrectly, or it I just can't because Trinket.io does not support it. The following is the code I currently have:

```
#python 2

from turtle import *
wn = Screen()
wn.setup(640,400,0,0)
wn.bgcolor("#4885ed")
shape("circle")
resizemode("user")
shapesize(5, 5, 12)
```

When I run this code I get the error:
`NameError: name 'resizemode' is not defined on line 10 in main.py`

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: If you are trying to change the size of the CIRCLE, you are doing fine, just by assigning larger values to the third input argument of shapesize... If not what you need, can you maybe elaborate more on "change the size of turtle"

Comment: I forgot to mention I get the error ```NameError: name 'resizemode' is not defined on line 10 in main.py```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if you go to https://trinket.io/docs/python you will find out that `resizemode()` and `shapesize()` are not mentioned as functions. I presume they have not been implemented into trinket interface.

Answer (score -1):

i think you can try this code

```
import turtle

a = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(640,400,0,0)
wn.bgcolor("#4885ed")
a.shape("circle")
a.resizemode("user")
a.shapesize(5, 5, 12)
```

Comment: this doesn't work in Trinket.io e.g. https://trinket.io/python/041c755b35